# Rotation of a line based on fixed point in flex4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

[image]

As in the figure i have three lines out of which `line1` and `line2` are fixed.
`line3` is derived from `line1` based on some angle say 70.I try to rotate the line3 but it deviate from the point x1 and x2.
I try the code like this
 `<s:Line xFrom="200" xTo="600" yFrom="310" yTo="310"/>`
 `<s:Line xFrom="200" xTo="600" yFrom="310" yTo="310" rotation="70"/>`

My doubts are

```
 - how to rotate line3 based on the point x1 and x2.  
 - how to find out the intersection point(x2,y2) of line2 and line3.
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: @J_A_X I define two line with same mxml and in one of the line control i used the rotation property.but rotation is based on the center point.

Comment: By default, flex normally uses the top left corner as the rotation point. Just edit your question and past your code.

Comment: Just wrap the line in a sprite and offset the line in sprite so the rotation point of the line is at 0,0 in the sprite. If you want more help do like JAX said and post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<s:Group x="200" y="310">
    <s:Line width="300">
        <s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="red"/></s:stroke>
    </s:Line>

    <s:Line width="300" rotation="-70">
        <s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="blue"/></s:stroke>
    </s:Line>
</s:Group>
```

The important you have to remember when rotating is the center of rotation, and that's top-left in this case (as J_A_X pointed out). So we just wrapped it in a Group at your x1,y1 position.

Now, I don't believe using it this way is exactly what you need, as you also asked for the intersection between line2 and line3. This calls for some math, and we can use math too to actually rotate the lines accordingly.

I will assume that line1 and line2 are horizontal, like in your drawing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

               initialize="computeStuff(70)">


    <s:Line id="line1" xFrom="200" yFrom="310" xTo="400" yTo="310"><s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="red"/></s:stroke></s:Line>
    <s:Line id="line2" xFrom="200" yFrom="210" xTo="400" yTo="210"><s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="green"/></s:stroke></s:Line>
    <s:Line id="line3" xFrom="200" yFrom="310"><s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="blue"/></s:stroke></s:Line>
    <s:Rect id="intersection" width="5" height="5"><s:fill><s:SolidColor color="red"/></s:fill></s:Rect>
    <s:HSlider id="slider" minimum="-90" maximum="90" value="70" change="computeStuff(slider.value)"/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function computeStuff(angle:Number):void {
                var u:Number = angle/180 * Math.PI;

                var len:Number = 300;
                line3.xTo = line3.xFrom + len * Math.cos(u);
                line3.yTo = line3.yFrom - len * Math.sin(u);

                // intersection:
                var d:Number = -(line3.yTo - line3.yFrom) / (line3.xTo - line3.xFrom);
                intersection.x = line2.xFrom + (line3.yFrom - line2.yFrom) / d; 
                intersection.y = line2.yFrom;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rotation will work when you specify absolute line position. Have you tried doing something like this:

```
<s:Line x="200" y="310" width="400"/> 
<s:Line x="200" y="310" width="400" rotation="70"/>
```

By default, flex should use the top-left of the component as a rotation point.  If the code above doesn't work, try to wrap it in a Group:

```
<s:Group rotation="70">
    <s:Line x="200" y="310" width="400"/> 
</s:Group>
```

Comment: it also have the same problem

Comment: Then I'm not following what you're trying to do because it's rotating perfectly for me...

Comment: I want something like this
`<mx:HRule x="64" y="334" width="345"/>`
`<mx:HRule x="64" y="334" width="345"  rotation="-30" />`  how can i   implement this using the line control

Comment: or can u please tell me how to find out the endpoints of a Hrule form its width and angle of rotation.